# Exporting and importing user's custom commands from Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, import, export

I have Texmaker on two different PCs, but only on one of them I defined custom commands in Texmaker. Is there a way to export these commands from one Texmaker and to import them on the other one?

[image]

Comment: I assume those are `Tags` so look in `texmaker.ini` in program root directory. Open the file with `notepad` and see if you will find your commands. Also before that you can `Option>>Settings file >> Save a copy of settings file` and import on the new pc.

Comment: Perfect answer @Mafsi thank you very much